# Unable to bind to local port - WSAEADDRINUSE

Tags: c++, network-programming, port, bind

We have a server application on Windows that fails to bind on the local port (3050) giving error `WSAEADDRINUSE -  Address already in use.`

However, I have checked using SysInternals Utility (**TCPView**) that no process is listening on that port.

Please suggest what can be the reason behind this and any workaround to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does netstat show for that port?

Answer (score 5):

That error condition will occur under two conditions:

1) Another socket is already bound to that address

2) A socket bound to that address was recently closed.

In the first case, I imagine that the problem is you are binding to that port number twice in the same program.

In the second case, I imagine that a previous run of your program exited or crashed less than 120 seconds before your test. By the time you run TCPView, the 120 seconds have passed.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will verify the above conditions.

Comment: I have checked in the code and it doesn't seem I am binding to the port twice. Moreover, I tried binding to other ports from 3050-3054 with same error but it binds correctly on port 3055! However TCPView does not show these ports in use by any process.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the underlying C++ code, you may be able to use `setsockopt()` with the argument `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket before you call `bind()`. This would allow your program to rebind to the given port, even if there is a socket from a previous program run 'lingering'.

Comment: I believe this would be possible only when the earlier socket was configured using SO_REUSEADDR option?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The idea would be to utilize this option every time you open the given socket, so when a crash does occur you don't run into the ADDRINUSE error upon restart.

Comment: @Gaurav No, you're not correct. That applies to UDP. The problem arises in TCP when an old connected port is in TIME_WAIT. Only the new socket needs SO_REUSEADDR.